# Java isn't displaying rectangle?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, paint

I'm trying it to display a rectangle at the specified location but it isn't showing up. The background is magenta but the rectangle is not there.

Also: How can I access more colors besides the "Color.(insert very few options here)"

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


class Screensaver {
    private final static int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;
    private final static int FRAME_WIDTH = 600;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame win;
        Container contentPane;
        Graphics g;


        win = new JFrame();
        win.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        win.setVisible(true);
        contentPane = win.getContentPane();
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
        g = contentPane.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(80, 350, 400, 250);

    }
}
```

Comment: `g = contentPane.getGraphics();`  Never do that, instead, paint when requested to paint.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be painting in main(); it would be better to extend JPanel, change paintComponent(), and add the panel to the JFrame.

```
public class PaintPanel extends JPanel {

    public PaintPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g); // This paints the background

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(80, 350, 400, 250);
    }
}
```

And in main():

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(new PaintPanel());
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

If you want to make your own Colors, you can use the new Color(int red, int green, int blue) constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Screensaver {

    private final static int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;
    private final static int FRAME_WIDTH = 600;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame win;
        Container contentPane;
        win = new JFrame();
        win.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        win.setVisible(true);
        Component comp = new Component();
        contentPane = (Container) win.getContentPane().add(comp);


    }
    }

    class Component extends JComponent {

    @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.magenta);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(80, 350, 400, 250);
    }
}
```

and about the color , you van create new Color and set the RED,GREEN,BLUE as you want , Try this :

```
g.setColor(new Color(red, green, blue));
```

Comment: The recommend method for performing custom painting is paintComponent. You should also be calling super.paint/pantComponent

Comment: i don't know what is the problem with `paint` method?? i run it and it is ok , so please tell me where is the error?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0261__2D-Graphics/DrawRectangle.htm : java Tutorial

Comment: Take a read through [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), the recommended method for performing customing painting is paintComponent. paint is responsible for calling paintConent, paintBoreder and paintComponents amongst other things, it does to much to simply circumvent. Also, you'd be potentionally painting over any child components

Comment: i edit my answer , but in this case there is no difference between the  two method ,isn't it?

Comment: As to the result, probably not, but as to functionality, there's a lot

Comment: Also, beware that JComponent is transparent by default, which makes it even more important to be calling super.paintCompaont, as it will prepare the Graphics context correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to draw stuff create a class that inherits from a Swing container, JComponent, JPanel, etc. and override the paint(Graphics g) method. If you see the magenta background then contentPane must have been added. What's probably happening is its painting the magenta background over your rectangle, but that's just a guess. Try this...

```
public class ContentPane extends JComponent {
     public ContentPane() {

     }

     @Override
     public void paint(Graphics g) {
          g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
          g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

          g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
          g.fillRect(80, 350, 400, 250);

     }
}
```

Then in your main class instantiate an object of the ContentPane class and add it to your JFrame. The call to repaint() is probably unnecessary but that will make sure it gets painted. You can also try messing around with the paintComponent(Graphics g) method, there is a difference between the two, I believe its the order they're called from the update method but I'm probably wrong about that, however that should solve your problem.

As for colors, consult the API. You can pass RGB values into the Color constructor to create all sorts of colors. Color color = new Color(int red, int green, int blue). I think that is the easiest way to create custom colors but like I said its all in the API. Hope this helps.

Comment: The recommend method for performing custom painting would be paintComponent. You should be calling super.paint and up you should NEVER call repaint within any paint method EVER

Comment: Correct, I just threw it in there to ensure everything got painted but you're right it should be called from another thread. I'll edit it right now.

Comment: Repaint should be called for within the context on the EDT, just not within any paint methods

Comment: It would be nice if you called `super.paint`.  This is EXTREMELY important if you are going to extend from `JComponent` as it is transparent by default and part of `paint`s job is to correctly prepare the `Graphics` context for painting. You will end up with nasty paint side effects if you don't

Comment: If I had set the background color of the JComponent using the setBackground() method as in the original code that would be necessary but you'll notice in my example I first paint my own background inside the paint() method because for something like this I prefer to draw the whole component myself instead of using the default methods which is also why I prefer a JComponent over a JPanel for this type of thing, but that's a matter of preference and your way is probably the proper way to do it for reasons you mentioned though I personally have not come across a situation like that.

Comment: It doesn't change the fact that you've broken the paint chain. Paint is responsible for painting the background, border and child components, even if you don't have any of these things in your example, it still,makes it bad example that teaches bad habits to people who don't know better. And now all you've done is to discard the opacity property of the component instead

Comment: I understand and again, your way is likely the correct way to do it. All I did was provide one example that does what was asked. Instead of overriding the paint() or paintComponent() methods why not use a null LayoutManager and draw another JPanel with a setBackground(Color) to set the color and setBounds(int, int, int, int) to set the location and size? I've run into problems when trying to combine default methods with custom paint() methods and that is why I prefer to use built in methods or custom methods but not both if I can help it.

Answer (score -1):

The rectangle is drawn once, however every time the JFrames repaint() method is called it erases it and draws the basic Components. To add custom drawing in JFrames you have to override the paint method. Here I improved your code slightly to get you started down that path. As you can see you want to draw the box in the Paint method. I made a Container element that does your drawing and removed the background color, adding it to the paint method as well.

try this

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JavaApplication10 {
    private final static int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;
    private final static int FRAME_WIDTH = 600;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame win = new JFrame();
        win.setContentPane(new MyBoxContainer());
        win.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        win.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class MyBoxContainer extends Container {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(80, 350, 400, 250);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1- want extend from an AWT component when the OP is using Swing 2- the recommend method for custom painting is JComponent#paintComponent